# DC/OS installation failure during preflight

Tags: mesosphere, dcos

I am using 5 cloud-based VMs to install DC/OS
1 mesos master
3 mesos agent
1 launching VM
I have installed Docker on my launching VM and start installing DC/OS. It is running successfully during install_prereqs stage without any errors. But it's failing during preflight with below errors for each of my VM system.

STDERR:
          Connection to 129.114.18.235 closed.

STDOUT:
        Running preflight checks /opt/dcos_install_tmp/dcos_install.sh: line 225: getenforce: command not found

```
      Checking if docker is installed and in PATH: FAIL 
      Checking if unzip is installed and in PATH: FAIL 
      Checking if ipset is installed and in PATH: FAIL 
      Checking if systemd-notify is installed and in PATH: FAIL 
      /opt/dcos_install_tmp/dcos_install.sh: line 387: systemctl: command not found
      Checking if systemctl is installed and in PATH: FAIL 
      Checking Docker is configured with a production storage driver: /opt/dcos_install_tmp/dcos_install.sh: line 285: docker: command not found
```

Do I need to install all  the required software into my master and agents VMS? Please guide.

Comment: Did you read https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/installing/custom/system-requirements/ already?

Comment: From my experience it is mandatory that the VMs are in an absolute fresh state. You should refrain from installing / updating anything after having the machines installed with the base OS.

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar setup but using straight vm's.  We found docker needs to be running on all nodes, including masters, before running the install.  Also, make sure you look at: `/etc/sysconfig/docker-storage`and have:    `DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS= -s overlay`set in the file on all nodes.
I don't believe this is the production setup but should get you running. You also may want to check the privilege of the user executing the install on the remote nodes, does it have permission to see/run systemctl?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with the DC/OS web installer in version 1.9

I solved the error after double-checking the bootstraps machines's private key in the web form. To create the key, log into the bootstrap machine and run:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
$ for i in `cat dcos-ips.txt`; do ssh-copy-id root@$i; done
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```